# I am trying to implement Particle filter for tracking in opencv, But it is stopping after some time

Tags: opencv, particle-filter

I am trying to implement particle filter , on the basis of the udacity course on programming a car and few other online videos.

The measurement for the particle filter i.e (x,y) of the car,is found by subtracting the consecutive frames.

the code is

```
//motionTracking.cpp

#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include"particle filter.h"
#include<Windows.h>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



#define max 5
float dt = 1.0;
static Mat A = (Mat_<float>(4, 4) << 1.0, 0.0, dt, 0, 0, 1.0, 0.0, dt, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
static Mat Prior = (Mat_<float>(4, 1) << 0, 0, 0, 0);
static Mat Predict = (Mat_<float>(4, 1) << 0, 0, 0, 0);
Mat Ex = (Mat_<float>(4, 4) << dt*dt / 4.0, 0, dt*dt*dt / 2.0, 0, 0, dt*dt / 4.0, 0, dt*dt*dt / 2.0, dt*dt*dt / 2.0, 0.0, dt*dt, 0, 0, dt*dt*dt / 2.0, 0, dt*dt);
float X_R = 0.001;

static Mat Particle[max];
Mat Particle2[max];
float weight[max];
void intialise_particles(int a,int b)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        Particle[i] = (Mat_<float>(4, 1) << rand() % a, rand() % b, 0, 0);
        weight[i] = 1;
    }

}

void filter(float *a, float *b)
{
    float x_m = *a;
    float y_m = *b;
    //for the car
    Predict = A*Prior;

    //updating the particles
    float sum = 0;
    float maximum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        Particle[i] = A*Particle[i];
        Particle[i].at<float>(0, 0) += uniformRandom();
        Particle[i].at<float>(1, 0) += uniformRandom();
        float xW, yW;

        xW = (1 / sqrt(2 * 3.14*X_R))*exp((-1 * (x_m - Particle[i].at<float>(0, 0)) *  (x_m - Particle[i].at<float>(0, 0))) / 2.0*X_R);
        yW = (1 / sqrt(2 * 3.14*X_R))*exp((-1 * (y_m - Particle[i].at<float>(1, 0)) *  (x_m - Particle[i].at<float>(1, 0))) / 2.0*X_R);
        weight[i] = sqrt(xW*xW + yW*yW);
        sum += weight[i];
        if (weight[i] > maximum)
            maximum = weight[i];
    }

    //normalizing the weights;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        weight[i] = weight[i] / sum;

    //resampling

//index = int(random.random() * N)
    int index = rand() % max;
    float beta = 0.0;
        //mw = max(W)
        float mw = maximum;

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        beta += rand()*2.0*mw;
        while (beta>weight[index])
        {
            beta -= weight[index];
            index = (index + 1) % max;

        }
        Particle2[i] = Particle[index];
    }

    x_m = 0;
    y_m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        Particle[i] = Particle2[i];
        x_m += weight[i] * Particle[i].at<float>(0, 0);
        y_m += weight[i] * Particle[i].at<float>(1, 0);

        *a = x_m;
        *b = y_m;
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << Particle;



}













//our sensitivity value to be used in the absdiff() function
const static int SENSITIVITY_VALUE = 20;
//size of blur used to smooth the intensity image output from absdiff() function
const static int BLUR_SIZE = 10;
//we'll have just one object to search for
//and keep track of its position.
int theObject[2] = { 0, 0 };
//bounding rectangle of the object, we will use the center of this as its position.
Rect objectBoundingRectangle = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);





//int to string helper function
string intToString(int number){

    //this function has a number input and string output
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}

void searchForMovement(Mat thresholdImage, Mat &cameraFeed){




    static unsigned int time = 0;
    bool objectDetected = false;
    Mat temp;
    thresholdImage.copyTo(temp);
    //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
    //findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );// retrieves all contours
    findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);// retrieves external contours

    //if contours vector is not empty, we have found some objects
    if (contours.size()>0)objectDetected = true;
    else objectDetected = false;

    if (objectDetected){
        //the largest contour is found at the end of the contours vector
        //we will simply assume that the biggest contour is the object we are looking for.
        vector< vector<Point> > largestContourVec;
        largestContourVec.push_back(contours.at(contours.size() - 1));
        //make a bounding rectangle around the largest contour then find its centroid
        //this will be the object's final estimated position.
        objectBoundingRectangle = boundingRect(largestContourVec.at(0));
        int xpos = objectBoundingRectangle.x + objectBoundingRectangle.width / 2;
        int ypos = objectBoundingRectangle.y + objectBoundingRectangle.height / 2;

        //update the objects positions by changing the 'theObject' array values
        theObject[0] = xpos, theObject[1] = ypos;
    }
    //make some temp x and y variables so we dont have to type out so much
    int x = theObject[0];
    int y = theObject[1];


    float ParX, ParY;
    ParX = x;
    ParY = y;
    filter(&ParX, &ParY);
    ParX = (int)ParX;
    ParY = (int)ParY;

    //Particle filter estimate
    circle(cameraFeed, Point(ParX, ParY), 20, Scalar(0, 0,255), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(ParX, ParY), Point(ParX, ParY - 25), Scalar(0, 0,255), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(ParX, ParY), Point(ParX, ParY + 25), Scalar(0, 0,255), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(ParX, ParY), Point(ParX - 25, ParY), Scalar(0, 0,255), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(ParX, ParY), Point(ParX + 25, ParY), Scalar(0, 0,255), 2);


    //draw some crosshairs around the object
    circle(cameraFeed, Point(x, y), 20, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(x, y), Point(x, y - 25), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(x, y), Point(x, y + 25), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(x, y), Point(x - 25, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    line(cameraFeed, Point(x, y), Point(x + 25, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    //write the position of the object to the screen
    putText(cameraFeed,"Tracking object at (" + intToString(x)+","+intToString(y)+")",Point(x,y),1,1,Scalar(255,0,0),2);



}
int main(){


    //some boolean variables for added functionality
    bool objectDetected = false;
    //these two can be toggled by pressing 'd' or 't'
    bool debugMode = false;
    bool trackingEnabled = false;
    //pause and resume code
    bool pause = false;
    //set up the matrices that we will need
    //the two frames we will be comparing
    Mat frame1, frame2;
    //their grayscale images (needed for absdiff() function)
    Mat grayImage1, grayImage2;
    //resulting difference image
    Mat differenceImage;
    //thresholded difference image (for use in findContours() function)
    Mat thresholdImage;
    //video capture object.
    //  Mat frame1, frame2;
    string a = "f (";

    string b = ").png";
    unsigned int f = 1;
    frame1 = imread(a + intToString(f) + b);

    intialise_particles(frame1.rows, frame1.cols);
    for (int k = 0; k < max; k++)
    {
        cout << Particle[k];
        cout << "\n";
    }

    while (1){

        //we can loop the video by re-opening the capture every time the video reaches its last frame

        while (1){
            //cout << f;
            //read first frame
            //capture.read(frame1);
            string abcd = a + intToString(f) + b;
            //cout << abcd;
            //char abc = getchar();

            frame1 = imread(a + intToString(f) + b);
            //convert frame1 to gray scale for frame differencing
            cv::cvtColor(frame1, grayImage1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

            //grayImage1.convertTo(grayImage2, CV_32F);
            //copy second frame
            //capture.read(frame2);

            if (f == 449)
                f = 0;
            frame2 = imread(a + intToString(f + 1) + b);

            f++;

            //convert frame2 to gray scale for frame differencing
            cv::cvtColor(frame2, grayImage2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            /*capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, position);
            position = position + 1;
            if (position > t)
            position = 0;*/
            //grayImage2.convertTo(grayImage2, CV_32F);
            //perform frame differencing with the sequential images. This will output an "intensity image"
            //do not confuse this with a threshold image, we will need to perform thresholding afterwards.
            cv::absdiff(grayImage1, grayImage2, differenceImage);
            //threshold intensity image at a given sensitivity value
            cv::threshold(differenceImage, thresholdImage, SENSITIVITY_VALUE, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            if (debugMode == true){
                //show the difference image and threshold image
                cv::imshow("Difference Image", differenceImage);
                cv::imshow("Threshold Image", thresholdImage);
            }
            else{
                //if not in debug mode, destroy the windows so we don't see them anymore
                cv::destroyWindow("Difference Image");
                cv::destroyWindow("Threshold Image");
            }
            //blur the image to get rid of the noise. This will output an intensity image
            cv::blur(thresholdImage, thresholdImage, cv::Size(BLUR_SIZE, BLUR_SIZE));
            //threshold again to obtain binary image from blur output
            cv::threshold(thresholdImage, thresholdImage, SENSITIVITY_VALUE, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            if (debugMode == true){
                //show the threshold image after it's been "blurred"

                imshow("Final Threshold Image", thresholdImage);

            }
            else {
                //if not in debug mode, destroy the windows so we don't see them anymore
                cv::destroyWindow("Final Threshold Image");
            }

            //if tracking enabled, search for contours in our thresholded image
            if (trackingEnabled){

                searchForMovement(thresholdImage, frame1);
                for (int k = 0; k < max; k++)
                {
                    int a = (int)Particle[k].at<float>(0, 0);
                    int b = (int)Particle[k].at<float>(1, 0);
                    circle(frame1, Point(a, b), 1, Scalar(0, 0,255), 2);


                }

            }



            //show our captured frame
            imshow("Frame1", frame1);
            //waitKey(10);




            //imshow("Frame1", frame2);
            //check to see if a button has been pressed.
            //this 10ms delay is necessary for proper operation of this program
            //if removed, frames will not have enough time to referesh and a blank 
            //image will appear.
            switch (waitKey(10*2 )){

            case 27: //'esc' key has been pressed, exit program.
                return 0;
            case 116: //'t' has been pressed. this will toggle tracking
                trackingEnabled = !trackingEnabled;
                if (trackingEnabled == false) cout << "Tracking disabled." << endl;
                else cout << "Tracking enabled." << endl;
                break;
            case 100: //'d' has been pressed. this will debug mode
                debugMode = !debugMode;
                if (debugMode == false) cout << "Debug mode disabled." << endl;
                else cout << "Debug mode enabled." << endl;
                break;
            case 112: //'p' has been pressed. this will pause/resume the code.
                pause = !pause;
                if (pause == true){
                    cout << "Code paused, press 'p' again to resume" << endl;
                    while (pause == true){
                        //stay in this loop until 
                        switch (waitKey()){
                            //a switch statement inside a switch statement? Mind blown.
                        case 112:
                            //change pause back to false
                            pause = false;
                            cout << "Code Resumed" << endl;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }



            }
        }
        //release the capture before re-opening and looping again.
        //      capture.release();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

the random number generator for normal distribution is done by the functions inside the header file.

```
    double uniformRandom()
{
    return ((double)(rand()) + 1.) / ((double)(RAND_MAX)+1.);
}
// return a normally distributed random number
double normalRandom()
{
    double u1 = uniformRandom();
    double u2 = uniformRandom();
    return cos(8.*atan(1.)*u2)*sqrt(-2.*log(u1));
}
```

The code works fine, but when i turn on the tracking, then it runs for some frames and hangs after that.

The input files are here [input files](http://www.filedropper.com/f141)

Comment: are `xW = (1 / sqrt(2 * 3.14*X_R))*exp((-1 * (x_m - Particle[i].at<float>(0, 0)) *  (x_m - Particle[i].at<float>(0, 0))) / 2.0*X_R);` and the next two lines your likelihood computation? Can you explain what you are doing there, no time to try to understand that from zero.

Comment: @Micka   yes they are the likelihood computation for computing the weights.. I I assumed it to be gaussian. Got the value for x and y both, separately, n took a sqrt(x**2+y**2).. Am i going wrong

Comment: I think you should try to find some better likelihood like some kind of feature matching, template matching or histogram matching. Otherwise your particle filter has no REAL clue about the quality/weight of a sample and will probably lose the track.

Comment: thanks @Micka I vl try something then